# Rearranging a matrix/vector formula

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given the vector-matrix expression

$$\mathbf{x} = (A+f(N)\mathbf{de}^T)\mathbf{x}$$

Where $A$ is a matrix, $\mathbf{d,e,x}$ are vectors and $f$ maps to the scalars. Show that this may be written in the form

$$\mathbf{x} = y(I-A)^{-1}\mathbf{d},\qquad y=f(N)\mathbf{e}^T\mathbf{x}$$

---

So firstly I tried:

$$(I-A)\mathbf{x} = f(N)\mathbf{de}^T\mathbf{x}$$

$$\implies \mathbf{x} = f(N)(I-A)^{-1}\mathbf{de}^T\mathbf{x}$$

$$\implies \mathbf{x} = f(N)\mathbf{e}^T\mathbf{x}(I-A)^{-1}\mathbf{d}$$

$$\implies \mathbf{x} = y(I-A)^{-1}\mathbf{d}$$

However I don't think this is correct since I have moved the $\mathbf{e}^T\mathbf{x}$. I also thought if we multiply step $1$ by $\mathbf{e}^T\mathbf{x}(I-A)^{-1}$ we get

$$\mathbf{e}^T\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x} = f(N)\mathbf{e}^T\mathbf{x}(I-A)^{-1}\mathbf{d}\mathbf{e}^T\mathbf{x}$$

$$\implies \mathbf{e}^T\mathbf{x} = y(I-A)^{-1}\mathbf{d}\mathbf{e}^T$$

However I'm not sure how to deal with the extra $\mathbf{e}^T$. Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: What set does $f$ map to?

Comment: If $e$ and $x$ are vectors, $e^Tx$ is a scalar, so you can move it like you did. But as @mvw pointed it is not clear what $f(N)$ should be (matrix? scalar?), so you may have a problem with the rest. Also in your second suggestion it is not correct to "simplify" the $x$ on the right because the matrix $de^T$ is not injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $f$ maps to scalar values, we have
\begin{align}
x &= (A + f(N) de^T) x \\
&= Ax + d f(N)e^T x \\
&= Ax + d y
\end{align}
which gives
\begin{align}
(I - A) x &= d y \iff \\
x &= (I-A)^{-1} d y
\end{align}
Then we have
$$
y = f(N) e^T x
$$
is a scalar too, so
$$
x = y (I-A)^{-1}d
$$